# where if statement in linq query c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a linq query that works perfectly, however, I would like to avoid the whole "where" filter if I have an empty `mySTRINGVAR`, however when I included if statement it broke the query! thanks in advance for your help.

So this is what I have and this works perfectly!!:

```
var records = from school in schools
   join tableA in tableAs on someid equals anotherid into tableC
   from tableD in tableC.Where(c => c.tablefield == mySTRINGVAR).DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new { etc.. }
```

However, I am trying to not include any "where" statement if my `mySTRINGVAR` is null or empty:

```
var records = from school in schools
   join tableA in tableAs on someid equals anotherid into tableC
   from tableD in tableC.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new { etc.. }
```

Comment: Are you aware, that there is no extension method `defaultifempty` ? Is that the issue?

Comment: `defaultifempty` is not the same as `DefaultIfEmpty`. What error are you getting, or what is not working right?

Comment: sorry its DefaultIfEmpty that i am using:) i have edited my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> however, i am trying to not include any "where" statement if my
>   mySTRINGVAR is null or empty:

Modify the `Where` like:

```
tableC.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySTRINGVAR) && c.tablefield == mySTRINGVAR)
```

Comment: isn't this similar to `Where(c=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.tablefield))`?

Comment: @KingKing, what about the comparison of `c.tablefield == mySTRINGVAR`

Comment: It should be `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySTRINGVAR)`

Comment: @Kaf, I had it like that, but after reading the statement modified it, You are right I guess it should be `!`

Comment: One question: isn't this method checking if `mySTRINGVAR` is `IsNullOrEmpty` for every record?

Comment: is it possible not to include the whole "where" statement? like not tableC.where()?

Comment: @Menew, not in LINQ expression, you have to write two different queries one with `Where` and one without, and then check if `mySTRINGVAR` is Null Or Empty and then execute the one required. May be [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) could help you, though not sure about it.

Comment: @KingKing: Agree with Habib.